# C# Regex Match Address - Mark groups optional

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a German address that I get in one string like "Example Street 5b". I want to split it in groups: Street, Number and Additional Information.

For example: address = Test Str. 5b

-> Street: "Test Str." Number: "5", Add.: "b"

My code looks like that:

```
string street = "";
string number = "";
string addition = "";
//this works:
string address = "Test Str. 5b";
//this doesn't match, but I want it in the street group:
//string address = "Test Str.";        
Match adressMatch = Regex.Match(address, @"(?<street>.*?\.*)\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*)\s*(?<addition>.*)");

street = adressMatch.Groups["street"].Value;
number = adressMatch.Groups["number"].Value;
addition = adressMatch.Groups["addition"].Value;
```

That code works well for the example and most other cases.

My problem:

If the adress does not contain a number, the function fails. I tried to add *? after the number group and several other things, but then the whole string got parsed into the "addition" and "street" and "number" remain empty. But if the number is missing, I want the string to parse into "street" and "number" and "addition" shall remain empty.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try making the first `.*?` greedy and wrap the number part with an optional group: [`(?<street>.*\.)(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?<addition>.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3cstreet%3e.*%5c.)(%3f%3a%5cs*(%3f%3cnumber%3e%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d*))%3f%5cs*(%3f%3caddition%3e.*)&i=Test+Str.+5b%0d%0aTest+Str.+b)

Comment: I still suggest the above regex, and in code, just check if the `adressMatch.Groups["number"].Success` is *True*, and if no, assign it the value of `adressMatch.Groups["addition"].Value`. See [**this C# demo**](http://ideone.com/ZpKaHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this: I'd match the street into the *street* group, then match the number - if any - into the *number* group, and then the rest into the *addition* group.

Then, if the number group does not succeed, the *addition* value should be moved to the *number* group, which can be done easily within C# code.

So, use

```
(?<street>.*\.)(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?<addition>.*) 
            ^^  ^^                         ^^
```

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cstreet%3E.*%5C.)(%3F%3A%5Cs*(%3F%3Cnumber%3E%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*))%3F%5Cs*(%3F%3Caddition%3E.*)&i=Test%20Str.%205b%0D%0ATest%20Str.%20b) (note the changes: the first `.*?` is turned greedy, the `*` quantifier after `\.` is removed, the *number* group is made optional together with the `\s*` in front).

Then, use this logic ([C# sample snippet](http://ideone.com/ZpKaHP)):

```
string street = "";
string number = "";
string addition = "";
//string address = "Test Str. 5b"; // => Test Str. |  5  |  b
string address = "Test Str. b"; // => Test Str. |  b  |  
Match adressMatch = Regex.Match(address, @"(?<street>.*\.)(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?<addition>.*)");
if (adressMatch.Success) {
    street = adressMatch.Groups["street"].Value;
    addition = adressMatch.Groups["addition"].Value;
    if (adressMatch.Groups["number"].Success)
        number = adressMatch.Groups["number"].Value;
    else 
    {
        number = adressMatch.Groups["addition"].Value;
        addition = string.Empty;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Street: {0}\nNumber: {1}\nAddition: {2}", street, number, addition);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thanks for the effort. I tried a different approach than regex and solved the problem with a for-loop and using char.IsNumber

Comment: Not Working for Mühlenweg 14.
I changed it to (?<street>.*(\.)?[ ])(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?<addition>.*)